# Changing column order in python pandas using pivot table pd

Tags: python, pandas

I would love to change the order of my pivot table using pd (pandas)

Current layout

Code:

```
pd.pivot_table(df.loc[filt], 
    index=['region','brand'],
    values['salesrevenue','contributionmargin','variablecost'])
```

The code is displaying contribution margin, salesrevenue and variablecost.

I would like to have this layout 'salesrevenue','contributionmargin','variablecost', is there a way to change this?

```
pd.pivot_table(df.loc[filt],
    index=['region','brand'], 
    values=['salesrevenue','contributionmargin','variablecost'])
```

Comment: Hi Hendrik! Welcome to the SO. If you could add some sample data, and your expected output, community could help you in a more efficient way.

Comment: Welcome, Hendrik. Also, formatting correctly the code using markdown would make the question much more easy to read and understand.